# Nuxt[2] - Google Tag Manager(@nuxtjs/gtm) run only in production

Tags: google-analytics, nuxt.js, google-tag-manager

```
buildModules: ['@nuxtjs/gtm'],

gtm: {
  id: 'GTM-5TAAAA',
  enabled: () => {
    return process.env.ENV === 'production'
  }
}
```

I have dev, stage and production environment.

([www.dev-example.com](http://www.dev-example.com)) ([www.stage-example.com](http://www.stage-example.com))([www.example.com](http://www.example.com))

I want GTA to work only in production but it works in all.

Comment: Having `enabled: process.env.ENV === 'production' || false` should be okay. You then need to define `ENV` properly on your various environments (dev, stage and production).

Answer (score 0):

Move your logic in publicRuntimeConfig (else the value is computed at build-time)
https://github.com/nuxt-community/gtm-module#runtime-config